# How to Use CDatabase to connect to SQL Server database with ODBC?

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

My program uses ADO to connect to SQL Server in Visual C++ 2008. Now it seems that ADO is out-dated and MS recommends to use ODBC again.

Therefore, I now study how to use ODBC to connect to SQL Server. I see there is a class CDatabase that can do that. However, there are no good article in introducing how to use CDatabase to connect to SQL Server via ODBC.

Basd on my research, it seems one can connect to SQL Server via ODBC in the following way:

1. Via a direct connection string like this one:

Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;
Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

2. Using ODBC administrator to create a DSN(Data Source Name), and then connect with DSN.

THen if 1 works, why do we need to create DSN?

Comment: Reality: ADO isn't the only thing that is legacy.

Comment: wasn't OLEDB resurrected in 2017? To answer your question, if 1 works then you don't really need the DSN

Comment: Visual C++ **2008** is also outdated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a ODBC DSN. A DSN simply allows one to externalize the ODBC configuration such that server name, driver. etc. can be configured in a common way for all ODBC applications.

It is not a requirement to use a DSN when you store connection string in an external file so that environment-specific values can be configured without code changes. Regardless of the technique used, be sure to protect secrets rather than storing as clear text.